# Android Sensor converting handle / type

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I'm using the proximity sensor in my app, and when I register the sensor I can see in the LogCat this line:

**07-11 17:14:26.049: E/SensorManager(26240): registerListener :: handle = 4  name= CM3663 Proximity Sensor delay= 10000 Listener= com.sampler.ProximitySampler@408093c8**

Now, I know and it's verified that the [TYPE_PROXIMITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_PROXIMITY) = 8. Than why in the log I get that the handle = 4 ??

Let's say this is a normal thing, how can I get the actual sensor type from that handle number? I cannot just convert this number to be the sensor type.
i.e How can I know that the handle=4 means TYPE_PROXIMITY?

Thanks;

Comment: why do you want to do that?... i mean how are you even obtaining a handle value without knowing the sensor-type in the first place?...

Comment: First, when you turning on some sensor, you can see in the logcat it's handle which is different from it's type. Second, you can achieve all operating sensor by each app from the system by java reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHAH!

There is a private method android.hardware.Sensor.getHandle() which returns the sensor handle number so I can make a map type to handle!